# How to restrict a function call only to the owner of a private key of a public key in a parameter (many users)?

Tags: contract-invocation, addresses, accounts, payable, modifiers

Let's say, there's something like a lottery. And there's a function in a smart contract that allows **ANY** user among `users` to check whether he's won something or not. If he has, it'll allocate the coins internally to his address and then will allow to be sent out to him.

How such a function would work?

I've come up with something like this:

```
constrct C1 {

  //.........
  struct User { /*..skipped..*/ };

  mapping(address => User) users;


  function checkIfAnythingToGrab(address payable _to) public payable {
    if (/* some checks if a user won */) {
      //.............

      // and then, if he's won ...
      bool res = _to.send(wonAmount);
      require(res, "Failed to send Ether");
  }
```

How would I ensure that only a user who has the private key of `_to` address, and who, of course, exists in `users` mapping, will be permitted to call this function?

Because, if that address has won something, it'll be sent coins to it.

Or, would there be no problem if a malicious user called the function and used his own address? If he actually won, he'd be sent coins to, which is the proper behaviour. And if he used an address of other user, the coins would be sent to the other user anyway. Right?

---

Note that it's not about the owner or admin of the smart contract.

Comment: Read here: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol

Comment: @GraphicalDot ownable has nothing to do with my question

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with signatures. In general the idea with private and public keys is that nobody knows the private key, but everyone know the public key (duh :P). In Ethereum the address of an account is derived from the public key. So you could require the user to submit the signature of some data and recover the address from it (see [`ecrecover`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=ecrecover#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions)) to perform the check.

That being said, it is probably easier to say that the `msg.sender` (the account that triggered the function) should be the winner. This way you don't rely on signatures and even support contract based wallets.

But as you said, for your use case it probably is even fine if there is no limitation on it, as you check if `_to` is the winner in any case and pay the reward to `_to` and not the account that triggered the function. So if someone else besides the winner triggers this method they are paying for the gas and get nothing.

To do a final judgement on this it would be required to see a more final state of the contract, as security of smart contracts depend on many details ;)